# react testing library Redux with thunk testing, action not being dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

i am trying to test if a like counter has been increased after user clicks a button. I am using react testing library where i find a button and preform `userEvent.click` this should dispatch an action behind the scenes and increment the counter where i can then assert the new value.

This works when i manually go through the ui but cannot get the test to work.

Button:

```
 <Button
      size="small"
      color="primary"
      onClick={() => dispatch(likePosts(post._id))}
    >
      <ThumbUpIcon fontSize="small" />
      Like {`${post.likeCount}`}
      {}
    </Button>
```

Thunk action:

```
export const likePosts = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.likePost(id);
    dispatch({ type: LIKE, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

I have also set up a test-util to help me test connected component [TEST UTIL LINK](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/articles/s/testing-redux-connected-components)
I have also added `applyMiddleware(thunk)` to support thunk when a for a connected component

test-util:

```
    import React from "react";
import { render as rtlRender } from "@testing-library/react";
import { legacy_createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
// Replace this with the appropriate imports for your project
import reducers from "../redux/reducers";

const render = (
  ui,
  {
    store = legacy_createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk)),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) => {
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  );
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
};

export * from "@testing-library/react";

export * from "@testing-library/jest-dom";
// override render method
export { render };
```

My Test:

```
import Post from "./Post";
import { render, screen } from "../../../utils/test-utils";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

describe("Post", () => {
  let initialState;
  beforeEach(() => {
    initialState = {
      _id: "1234",
      title: "post title",
      message: "post message",
      creator: "post creator",
      tags: ["postTag", "postTag"],
      selectedFile: "path/to/file",
      likeCount: 0,
      createdAt: "2022-07-20T23:54:25.251Z",
    };
  });

  test("should increment post likes when like button clicked", () => {
    render(<Post post={initialState} />, { initialState });

    const postLikeButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /Like/i });
    userEvent.click(postLikeButton);
    const clickedPostLikeButton = screen.getByRole("button", {
      name: /Like 1/i,
    }).textContent;

    // expect().toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(clickedPostLikeButton).toBe(100);
  });
});
```

Test error:

```
 TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button" and name `/Like 1/i`
```

That would suggest that the the action was not dispatched when then button was clicked in the test.

UPDATE:

The button is from MUI library:

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
```

The post prop is passed from its parent component `Posts`:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { Grid, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import Post from "./Post/Post";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Posts = ({ setCurrentId }) => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  const classes = useStyles();

  return !posts.length ? (
    <CircularProgress />
  ) : (
    <Grid
      className={classes.container}
      container
      alignItems="stretch"
      spacing={3}
    >
      {posts.map((post, index) => (
        <Grid key={index} item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Post key={post.id} post={post} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Also all of this works just fine when using the UI, its just in react testing library test the button onClick seems the not to dispatch `likePosts`

Comment: Could you provide the code of the `Button`? Or, does it come from a UI library? And where does `post` come from? Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @slideshowp2 i updated the post hopefully that helps and thx for having a look

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `redux-mock-store`?

```js
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
const mockStore = configureStore()
const store = mockStore(reducers) // add your reducers here

// ...
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        {children}
    </Provider>
)
```